# Roots of polynomial of degree 6

Tags: polynomials, roots

I'm struggling to find the complex roots of  $x^6-9x^3+8 = 0$. I've managed to find the real roots (1 and 2) by letting a variable, say $α = x^3$ and substituting where relevant, leading to a quadratic equation which I subsequently solved by factorization. I know this method is not at all helpful in finding complex roots though. :(

I would appreciate it if you could point me to the simplest way of finding the complex roots of this specific equation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, what you have done is a very good start for the full  root calculation. You now need to solve $\alpha^3=1$ and $\alpha^3=8$. The roots of the second equation are twice the roots of the first.

To solve $\alpha^3=1$, note that $\alpha^3-1=(\alpha-1)(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)$.

Comment: Thank you! I see what I did wrong! :)

Comment: You are welcome. For the roots of $\alpha^3=1$, they may want you to use complex exponential notation, the de Moivre formula. If you have not heard of it, don't worry about it.

Comment: Purely a personal preference, but I think it’s more instructive to show the nontrivial cube roots of unity by the expressions involving $\sqrt{-3}$, rather than by using the complex exponential.

Comment: I had left the factored expression for OP, guessing that the quadratic formula would be the expected tool. After a while, the complex exponential or trigonometric equivalent is best, since it captures the geometry. But only after a while.

Answer (score 2):

The method which you mentioned is helpful. In fact with $\alpha=x^3$ we have
$$\alpha^2-9\alpha+8=0$$
so the roots are
$$\alpha_1=1\quad \alpha_2=8$$
now 
$$x^3=1\iff x=\exp\left(\frac{2ik\pi}{3}\right),\quad k=0,1,2$$
and
$$x^3=8\iff x=2\exp\left(\frac{2ik\pi}{3}\right),\quad k=0,1,2$$

Comment: Thank you! :) I see it now!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Nice encouraging post!

Answer (score 1):

Solving $x^3=1$ gives $x=1$ and the other roots satisfy x^2+x+1=0. For these you may use the quadratic formula $x=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{-3}}{2}$.

Solving $x^3=8$ gives x=2 and the other roots satisfy x^2+2x+4=0. Use the quadratic formula $x=2\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{-3}}{2}=-1\pm \sqrt{-3}$.